# How to set CPU priority for multiple ActionBlocks running at the same time?

Tags: c#, tpl-dataflow, thread-priority

I have a bunch of `ActionBlocks`, each doing something different.

- The big one treats data, and is fed data continuously by a `TransformBlock`.
- 3 other `ActionBlocks` simply writing lines in 3 text files (logs).

It kinda works, except that the 3 logging `ActionBlocks` only start consuming data when the treatment `ActionBlock` is complete (so they write all the logging information in one go at the end of the program).

I was wondering if I could influence this behavior, to give a higher priority to the logging `ActionBlocks`?

Thanks for your help.

Code sample:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;

namespace dataflowtest
{
    class Program
    {
        const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        static readonly IReadOnlyCollection<string> charsSets = Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 8).ToList().AsReadOnly();
        static readonly Random random = new Random();

        static event EventHandler<string> MessageGot;

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var source = new TransformBlock<string, string>(GetMessage, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = -1, EnsureOrdered = false });
            var target = new ActionBlock<string>(Console.WriteLine);


            var programDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().CodeBase.Replace("file:///", ""));
            using var file1 = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(programDir, "file1.txt"));
            using var file2 = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(programDir, "file2.txt"));
            using var file3 = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(programDir, "file3.txt"));

            var fileAction1 = new ActionBlock<string>(file1.WriteLineAsync);
            var fileAction2 = new ActionBlock<string>(file2.WriteLineAsync);
            var fileAction3 = new ActionBlock<string>(file3.WriteLineAsync);

            MessageGot += async (_, e) => await fileAction1.SendAsync(e);
            MessageGot += async (_, e) => await fileAction2.SendAsync(e);
            MessageGot += async (_, e) => await fileAction3.SendAsync(e);

            using (source.LinkTo(target, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true }))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    await source.SendAsync(i.ToString() + '\t' + new string(charsSets.Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray()));
                }

                source.Complete();
                await target.Completion;
            }
        }

        private static async Task<string> GetMessage(string input)
        {
            int delay = random.Next(25, 6000);
            await Task.Delay(delay);
            string message = input.ToLowerInvariant() + '\t' + delay.ToString();

            MessageGot?.Invoke(null, message);

            return message;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect you will find different results if you run in non-debug mode.

Comment: Nope, the files remain empty until the program is over, then fill up instantly, in Release or Debug.

Comment: "I assume" - Why do you assume that? We'll need to see your code to help

Comment: "I assume" because that would make sense to me. I'm adding a small code sample that reproduces the issue for me.

Comment: What is the reason for `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = -1`?

Comment: It runs faster.

Comment: I see. The option `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = -1` allows unlimited concurrency, which is a bit too uncontrollable for my taste. I would prefer to limit the concurrency to a finite number.

Answer (score 2):

By default a `StreamWriter` will flush its buffer every 4,096 bytes. You probably want it to flush on every line written. So instead of this:

```
var fileAction1 = new ActionBlock<string>(file1.WriteLineAsync);
```

...do this:

```
var fileAction1 = new ActionBlock<string>(item =>
{
    file1.WriteLine(item);
    file1.Flush();
});
```

There is not benefit with using `WriteLineAsync` instead of `WriteLine`, since the underlying `FileStream` has not been opened with the [`FileOptions.Asynchronous`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileoptions) option.